# Qual motivo escolher para fechar esta pergunta?

Tags: debate

Creio que esta pergunta (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21668/7261) deve ser fechada, porque o perguntador pede para alguém fazer o trabalho dele, sem mostrar que já tenha tentado, etc.

Mas não sei qual motivo escolher nesse caso.

Comment: Acho que "amplo demais" ou "não está claro" podiam ser usadas... mas a resposta do Cigano foi meio que matadora, já que existe uma ferramenta pra fazer tal conversão. Com o -8 que já tem, nem sei se precisa fechar, está claro que não é bem vinda. Eu votaria pra *deletar* sem nem fechar antes.

Comment: @brasofilo Dei meu voto para fechar como "Amplo demais"

Comment: Me too, vamos poupar-lhe a agonia então

Answer (score 2):

Dei o empurrãozinho final e fechei como "descontextualizado" por considerar *off-topic*.

Comment: Eu fiquei na dúvida se fechava ou não, acabei só votando contra. Esse foi um exemplo extremo, mas tem muitas perguntas no site que beiram o "faz pra mim".

Comment: @bfavaretto Se já não houvessem 4 votos contra talvez eu ficasse na dúvida. Mas com os votos + essa pergunta do meta, deu pra ver que era consenso da comunidade! ;)